# error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set

Tags: react-native

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✔ Installing Ruby Gems
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 16.2M  100 16.2M    0     0  8484k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 8501k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.3M  100 12.3M    0     0  4197k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 4202k
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have tried Googling and using GPT to solve this problem, but it still doesn't work. Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Comment: Doesn't this help? "Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details."